# Mootools accordion inside another

Tags: mootools

This is a funny one... 
I have created a mootools accordion with tabs, each section appears when clicked. This works fine. Now within the first accordion that shows, I have another accordion that displays more data. This was to keep the area small with the mass of information that is needed on the page.

All works fine, the problem come when the information hidden is larger than the area that is worked our for the first tabs accordion, and it wont display.

does any-one either understand what i'm trying to say, or have an idea of a fix or workaround?

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think should fix your issue.

https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/24057/tickets/121-accordion-fix-a-way-to-get-nested-accordions-working-properly

It's a small article on how to resize the parent accordion when the nested accordion expands or collapses.